# dynamic method and the MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection

given the following classes:

```
class SomeBuilder<T>
{
    public static object Build(int index)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class SomeHelper
{
    public object GetBuildObj(object value)
    {
        var valuetype = value.GetType();
        var methodinfo = typeof(SomeBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(valuetype).GetMethod("Build");
        var handler = SomeDynamicHelper.GetMethodInvoker(methodinfo);
        var result = hander(null, new object[]{1});
    }
}
```

SomeBuilder was a generic type so i need a call to MakeGenericType() to make things right.

when i pass a normal type like 'class person' for the value, everything just works, that`s fine.

but when i pass a anonymous type like: new { id=1 }, the handler was successfully created. but invoke this dynamic handler i got a MethodAccessException with these messages:

`"method "SomeDynamicHelper.(System.Object, System.Objec[])"` try to access method `"SomeBuilder'1<<>f__AnonymousType0'1<System.Int32>>.Build(int)"` failed.

any help would be appreciated, thx.

btw, if you are interested in SomeDynamicHelper, plz see:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14593/A-General-Fast-Method-Invoker

**edit1:**

i did the call in main like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // pass a normal class, this will be fine
    var value = new Person { id = 1};
    new SomeHelper().GetBuildObj(value);  

    // pass a anonymous type
    var value = new { id = 1};
    new SomeHelper().GetBuildObj(value);  // oops, got a exception here!
}
```

**edit2:**

based on the comment i changed my code:

```
class SomeHelper
{
    public object GetBuildObj(object value)
    {
        //this time i do not use the value, but create a new inner value:
        var valuenew = new { id = 1 };
        var valuetype = valuenew.GetType();
        var methodinfo = typeof(SomeBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(valuetype).GetMethod("Build");
        var handler = SomeDynamicHelper.GetMethodInvoker(methodinfo);
        var result = hander(null, new object[]{1});
    }
}
```

well, this time there is no exception, but...unfortunately a new problem occured...may be i should open a new thread for the new problem.

thank you guys, for your attentions.

**edit3:**

hi, after some digging, i also found some useful information. say, the SomeDynamicHelper.GetMethodInvoker() code as below:

```
DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object[]) }, methodInfo.DeclaringType.Module);
```

this is the core we used here to dynamic create a method. for our context, we need to declare the anonymous type in same assembly with the SomeHelper and SomeBuilder. but, if we can`t do the declaration, what should we do?

ok, you can call DynamicMethod() with last parameter(the skipVisibility), set to true!

hope this will help others with the same problem :)

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "but when I pass a anonymous type" - it would really help if you'd provide a short but complete example which fails. An anonymous type doesn't *have* a method called `Build`...

Comment: sorry for unclearly. the i did some edit, hope this will help to clarify my question.

Comment: What is `SomeDynamicHelper`?

Comment: @CodingWithSpike hi, you could see this :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14593/A-General-Fast-Method-Invoker

Comment: @pinopino: What assembly are all these classes in? Bear in mind that anonymous types are internal.

Comment: The problem is in that `FastMethodInvoker` somewhere. I get an `InvalidProgramException` so it looks like it is generating invalid IL code for an anonymous type. That article is dated 2006. I forget exactly when anonymous types were added to .NET but it might have been after that was written.

Comment: @JonSkeet the Person and anonymous type were in same assembly while the SomeBuilder and SomeHelper were in antoher assembly. Person class was marked as Public, so...is this the reason cause this problem?

Comment: Possibly. I suggest you try putting them all in the same assembly and give it a go.

Comment: Alternatively you could mark `Person` as `internal` instead of `public` and see if that breaks it.

Comment: Anonymous types work nicely with the *dynamic* keyword.  Until you cross an assembly boundary.  Then it smile upside-down, the fields in an anonymous type have *internal* accessibility.  And the DLR enforces accessibility modifiers.  Kaboom.  Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

> "method "SomeDynamicHelper.(System.Object, System.Objec[])" try to access method "SomeBuilder'1<<>f__AnonymousType0'1>.Build(int)"

From this you can see that dynamic method try to run an internal\private method called Build, for that you got [MethodAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.methodaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

(The anonymous type is kept in a new generated class)

Adding `InternalVisibleTo` not always helping because it's helping only if you can rewrite the anonymous type assembly (manually or with interception) and only if the type and method are internals and not private.

In dynamic method you can bind the method to type\module, and to skip visibility check, but this help to access private members of the specified module, so again if the type you trying to access is in a different assembly and the type\method are private you can't do anything.

Well almost. There is a "secret" attribute that you inject to your assembly, called `IgnoreAccessChecksTo` and then in addition to bounded module and skip visibility maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly")]` in the same project where you define the anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with a C# class I tried to inject using IKVM-converted Guice. The fix was simply making the affected class (in this case probably `SomeBuilder`) public and everything worked fine.